# Cauchy's Theorem about finite groups using group actions, counting elements of X by orbit, how does that work?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm following along the proof of Cauchy's Theorem using group actions, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory) (proof 2).

The theorem states:

> If $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$ (the number of elements in G), then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.

The proof mentions:

> [...] As remarked, orbits in $X$ under this action either have size 1 or size $p$. The former happens precisely for those tuples $(x,x,\ldots,x)$ for which $x^p=e$. Counting the elements of $X$ by orbits, and reducing modulo $p$, one sees that the number of elements satisfying $x^p=e$ is divisible by $p$. [...]

(1) I'm not sure what "Counting the elements of $X$ by orbits" refers to. From what I think it means:

- For each element $x$ of $X$, I find the orbit of $x$
- Then I count the number of elements that have the same orbit?

(2) Then, how can I get from here to the conclusion that the number of elements satisfying $x^p=e$ is divisible by $p$?

Comment: Cauchy proved a lot of great theorems. You should edit your post to include a statement of the theorem under discussion. Take a look at our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your post, where it says *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question...*.

Comment: In $\begin{matrix}|&|&|\\|&|&|\end{matrix}$, you can count the sticks $\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\end{matrix}$, but you can also "count by rows" $\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{matrix}$ and add $3+3$. "Counting by orbits" is to count each orbit's size and then consider the sum of those sizes. You already know that the sizes of the orbits are $1$ or $p$. So, the total size of $X$ is a sum of a bunch of $p$ and a bunch of $1$. So, $a\cdot 1+b\cdot p=|X|$. Since $p\mid |X|$, then $p\mid a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let us first count the elements by orbits.

**Lemma**: Let $G$ be a $p$-group acting on a finite set $X$, then $|X^G|\equiv |X|\pmod p$, where $X^G$ is the set of fixed points of this group action, i.e., set of $x\in X$ such that $gx = x$ for all $g\in G$.

**Proof**: Since $X$ is finite, then say $X^G = \{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ has $n$ elements (notice that each element has orbit size $1$), and pick representatives $x_{n+1},\ldots, x_{n+m}$ for orbits of size more than $1$. Since $X$ can be partitioned into disjoint union of orbits, we know $X = \coprod\limits_{i=1}^{n+m}\operatorname{orb}(x_i)$. For $i > n$, we have $|\operatorname{orb}(x_i)| = \frac{|G|}{|\operatorname{stab}(x_i)|}$ by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, but since the orbit is greater than $1$ and $G$ is a $p$-group, then $p$ must divide $\operatorname{orb}(x_i)$ for $i > n$. By the partition, we have $|X| = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+m}|\operatorname{orb}(x_i)|\equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |\operatorname{orb}(x_i)| = |X^G|\pmod p. $

---

2. As mentioned, every orbit has size $1$ or $p$, and $X^G$ is exactly the set of tuples that are fixed with orbit size $1$, i.e., the elements $x\in X$ such that $(x,\ldots, x)\in X$ such that $x^p = e$. Recall from the proof that $X$ has size $|G|^{p-1}$, so it has size divisible by $p$, therefore $X^G$ also has size divisible by $p$.

Comment: "Since $X$ can be partitioned into disjoint union of orbits ..." - is that some known theorem? Like if $G$ acts on a set $X$, is it always the case that $X$ can be partitioned into disjoint unions of orbits?

Comment: Hang on, it's actually mentioned in my book before the theorem is defined that the union of the orbits forms a partition of $X$.

Comment: Orbits of size 1 are for elements in $X$ of the form $(x, x, ..., x)$ since these are unaffected by cyclic permutation. Let $a$ orbits be of size $1$ and $b$ orbits be of size $p$. Then $|X| = a \times 1 + b \times p$. Since $p | |X|$, $p|a$.  For $(e, e, ..., e)$, the orbit size is 1, so we always have at least one element of $X$ that has orbit size $1$. So there must be at least $p-1$ other elements $(x, x, ..., x)$ in $X$ with orbit size $1$ and thus we established there are $x$ for which $x^p=e$, that is, an $x$ of order $p$ (but different from the identity if the group is non-trivial.)

Comment: @Max Well yes. More formally, if you define a binary relation $\sim$ on $X$ such that $x\sim x'$ if and only if $x' = gx$ for some $g\in G$, then this becomes an equivalence relation, and the set of equivalence classes is exactly the set of orbits. (You should check this.)

Comment: and yes, this is the correct continuation to finish the proof :)

Comment: Thanks to you and @NDB for filling in the missing pieces. It's a quite interesting proof, I think so far one of the most difficult ones I encountered in group theory. Cheers!